# Why doesn't docker compose mount my volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After reading the docker docs on [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and how to use them in [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference), I believed this minimal example would work to mount a local directory as a volume:

#### `docky/Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["ash"]
```

#### `docky/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./bindme:/bound
```

But the volume isn't mounted:

```
$ docker-compose build
Building server
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> b14afc6dfb98
Step 2/2 : ENTRYPOINT ["ash"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 68fcd94074c9
Successfully built 68fcd94074c9
Successfully tagged docky_server:latest

$ docker run -it 68fcd94074c9
/ # ls /bound
ls: /bound: No such file or directory

$ docker inspect 68fcd94074c9 | grep -e Volumes -e Binds -e Mounts
            "Volumes": null,
            "Volumes": null,
```

The directory `./bindme` exists and contains a file. What am I missing/doing wrong?

- Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3
- docker-compose version 1.25.0

Comment: Docker build doesn't incorporate the mount in any way. You need to start the docker container with compose as well with `docker-compose up`.

Comment: With `up`, inspect shows a correct bind-mount entry, and also shows `"/bound": {}` in `Volumes`; however `/bound` still does not exist in the container

Answer (score 2):

You used Docker Compose to build your image, but you run it with Docker command, so your container configuration isn't used at all for runtime.

Use `docker-compose up -d` to launch your containers using your Docker Compose configuration. Then you shall have the volumes properly mounted :) !

Comment: This fixed my issue after hours of wondering wtf was going on.
Instead of `docker compose build` i needed to use `docker compose up --build` or `docker compose up -d --build` so the volume mounts worked during building

Answer (score 0):

Beginner mistake: I was not running compose with the options to keep stdin open as a TTY, so the container was exiting immediately, and I misread what was happening. The solution was just to add:

```
  server:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```